# How to program a macro to run in an emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm looking to create a bot to run on an android emulator(or real phone).
I've seen options like Nox player etc... But the API to create macros is extremely limited.

The bot will be provided a list of strings, then it will launch app X, and iterate the list of strings and type each string, wait 500ms, then type the next string etc...

My only idea right now is to write a script which will generate an extremely long macro for Nox, such as `write "str1", wait 500ms, write "str2", wait 500ms...` and 1000 times like that.
I rather have an approach like this `for x in list: write x, wait 500ms`.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio's [Espresso Test Reporter](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder) might make it easy to record a macro, although it doesn't work with the ARCore emulator test package.